# Kotlin Multipart Requests on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, multipartform-data

I would really appreciate some help with the problem I'm facing.

I'm trying to post an image to a [receipt parsing API](https://www.taggun.io/) and have problems constructing the actual request.

I have read and used much of the code from [this article](https://medium.com/@Tarek360/upload-file-via-multipart-post-method-in-kotlin-d43d3f025670) written by tarek on Medium to create a MultiPart class (with https) like the following:

*Multipart.kt*

```
package com.example.skopal.foodme.services

import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.OutputStream
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.URL
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection

class Multipart
/**
 * This constructor initializes a new HTTPS POST request with content type
 * is set to multipart/form-data
 * @param url
 * *
 * @throws IOException
 */
@Throws(IOException::class)
constructor(url: URL) {

    companion object {
        private val LINE_FEED = "\r\n"
        private val maxBufferSize = 1024 * 1024
        private val charset = "UTF-8"
    }

    // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
    private val boundary: String = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "==="
    private val httpsConnection: HttpsURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
    private val outputStream: OutputStream
    private val writer: PrintWriter

    init {

        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8")
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive")
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
        httpsConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary)
        httpsConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(maxBufferSize)
        httpsConnection.doInput = true
        httpsConnection.doOutput = true    // indicates POST method
        httpsConnection.useCaches = false
        outputStream = httpsConnection.outputStream
        writer = PrintWriter(OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset), true)
    }

    /**
     * Adds a upload file section to the request
     * @param fieldName  - name attribute in <input type="file" name="..."></input>
     * *
     * @param uploadFile - a File to be uploaded
     * *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun addFilePart(fieldName: String, uploadFile: File, fileName: String, fileType: String) {
        writer.append("--").append(boundary).append(LINE_FEED)
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: file; name=\"").append(fieldName)
            .append("\"; filename=\"").append(fileName).append("\"").append(LINE_FEED)
        writer.append("Content-Type: ").append(fileType).append(LINE_FEED)
        writer.append(LINE_FEED)
        writer.flush()

        val inputStream = FileInputStream(uploadFile)
        inputStream.copyTo(outputStream, maxBufferSize)

        outputStream.flush()
        inputStream.close()
        writer.append(LINE_FEED)
        writer.flush()
    }

    /**
     * Adds a header field to the request.
     * @param name  - name of the header field
     * *
     * @param value - value of the header field
     */
    fun addHeaderField(name: String, value: String) {
        writer.append("$name: $value").append(LINE_FEED)
        writer.flush()
    }

    /**
     * Upload the file and receive a response from the server.
     * @param onSuccess
     * *
     * @param onFailure
     * *
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @Throws(IOException::class)
    fun upload(onSuccess: (String) -> Unit, onFailure: ((Int) -> Unit)? = null) {
        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush()
        writer.append("--").append(boundary).append("--")
                .append(LINE_FEED)
        writer.close()

        try {
            // checks server's status code first
            val status = httpsConnection.responseCode
            if (status == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                val reader = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(httpsConnection.inputStream))
                val response = reader.use(BufferedReader::readText)
                httpsConnection.disconnect()
                onSuccess(response)
            } else {
                onFailure?.invoke(status)
            }

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

    }

}
```

And I'm calling the above class from:

*ReceiptRecognitionApi.kt*

```
fun parseReceipt(file: File, cb: (String) -> Unit) {
    println("parseReceipt_1")

    Thread {
        val multipartReq = Multipart(URL(baseUrl))
        multipartReq.addHeaderField("apikey", taggunApiKey)
        multipartReq.addHeaderField("Accept", "application/json")

        multipartReq.addFilePart("file", file, "receipt.jpg", "image/jpeg")

        multipartReq.upload(
                onSuccess = { response: String ->
                    cb(response)
                },
                onFailure = { responseCode: Int ->
                    cb("$responseCode")
                })

    }.start()
}
```

The problem is that after initialisation of a Multipart object, I cannot append any headers or data to it. E.g. if the two `addHeaderField`-calls within the `parseReceipt`-function call is moved to the `init`-block in *Multipart.kt*, the headers are in the request, but otherwise not.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using an HTTP library (e.g. Fuel) instead?

Comment: @m0skit0 Apart from making the application safe, the api I'm using (taggun) is requiring https connections.

Comment: Making the app safe? What do you mean? Using a library does not make your app less safe (most likely even the opposite unless you're a security expert). Most if not all HTTP libraries support HTTPS out of the box.

Comment: @m0skit0 Oh, sorry, didn't know Fuel had support for HTTPS, which I btw meant with 'safe'. I'll look into it and try solving it that way.

Comment: You can see [here](https://github.com/kittinunf/Fuel) most examples actually use HTTPS :) IMO it is always better to use these libraries because these folks most likely already solved the same problems you're facing, unless ofc you want to dig into HTTP by yourself, that's why I asked if you had any specific reason for not using more advanced libraries :)

Comment: @m0skit0 All right :) Thanks for your advice, I'll post a solution here later on.

Answer (score 2):

Usage of a third-party library solved my problem:

```
Fuel.upload(path = baseUrl, method = Method.POST)
            .header(TaggunConstants.taggunHeader(taggunApiKey))
            .dataParts { _, _ -> listOf(DataPart(file, "file", "image/jpeg")) }
            .responseJson { _, _, result ->
                result.fold(
                        success = { data ->
                            cb(gson.fromJson(data.content, Receipt::class.java))
                        },
                        failure = { error ->
                            println("An error of type ${error.exception} happened: ${error.message}")
                            cb(null)
                        }
                )
            }
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is just what I am looking for.